# Playwright using JS ,getting - page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached? ===== logs ====== navigating to "URL", waiting until "load"

Tags: playwright

Trying to implement Playwright with java script to one of my new projects using POM framework but getting this error as below

page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached?
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "URL", waiting until "load"
============================================================

**Test code**

```
const {test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');
const {LoginPage} = require('../pageobjects/LoginPage');

test('Test 1',async({page})=>
{
    const username = "SOMEUSERNAME";
    const password = "EQPun9wSe4EaNx7Z";
   const loginPage =  new LoginPage(page);
   loginPage.goTo();
   loginPage.validLogin(username,password);
});
```

**pages code**

```
class LoginPage{

constructor(page)
{
   this.page = page;
   this.UserName = page.locator("[name='email']");
   this.password = page.locator("[name='password']");
   this.login = page.locator("#loginSubmit");
}

async goTo()
 {
    await this.page.goto("**URL**");
    
    
 }

async validLogin(username,password)
{
   await this.UserName.type(username);
   await this.password.type(password);
   await this.login.click();
   
}
}
module.exports={LoginPage};
```

Comment: Debugging related issue here https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18137

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but in this code

```
test('Test 1',async({page})=>
{
   const username = "SOMEUSERNAME";
   const password = "EQPun9wSe4EaNx7Z";
   const loginPage =  new LoginPage(page);
   loginPage.goTo();
   loginPage.validLogin(username,password);
});
```

You're supposed to `await loginPage.goTo()`, otherwise it happens in sync with the validLogin (which you should also await) and this causes the error.